# Laravel в vee-validate, как указать на русском

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Я установил vee-validate для laravel, чтобы во vue можно было без перезагрузки проверять значения форм. Я сделал уже: `<input  v-validate="'min:6|max:31'" name="name"` , и у меня теперь в форме высвечивается на английском,а как сделать значения чтобы были на русском, то есть вместо `"The name field must be at least 6 characters."` , указывало к примеру "Поле должно содержать как минимум 6 символов" , то читаю офф. документацию и что-то не могу найти как это сделать. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

У vee-validate есть [встроенный механизм локализации сообщений](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#localized-files).

Чтобы сообщения стали русскими надо в главный файл vue.js добавить что-то такое:

```
import ru from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/ru';
import VeeValidate, { Validator } from 'vee-validate';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

// здесь происходит изменение локали
Validator.localize('ru', ru);
```

Предложения/добавления к переводу можно делать в виде pull request'ов на [их github'e](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/blob/master/locale/ru.js).